# File.CopyTo error

Tags: c#

I have a C# program that queries a remote database for an image file based on a key number. When it finds a match, it locates the file locally (on the server where the program is run) and copies it to a temporary local directory, from where the image is served up in the user's browser. However, I am getting a COM error directed at the file.CopyTo line of the program. The program DOES successfully locate the file and copy it to the temp directory, so it actually works, but for some reason, it apparently doesn't get a success message back or something, and so it stops before returning the filename back to the module that would serve it up in the browser. My apologies if this is too vague. Below is the Error, and then I have put the line of code it points to. There is really not much more to add, as it apparently has what it needs to be successful, but doesn't seem to acknowledge it. Let me know if I need to post more Anyway...

---

### Server Error in '/Indus' Application.

DB-0039 An error occurred while copying a file. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   DB-0039 An error occurred while copying a file.

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [COMException (0x80004005): DB-0039 An error occurred while copying a
>   file.]    XtenderSolutions.interop.AEXDBLib.IObjectFile.CopyTo(Object
>   FileName) +0    ip_axdb.AXNetConnect.GetAXDocuments(String FieldValue)
>   in C:\IndusAXProject2013\IP_AXDb\AXDB\AXNetConnect.cs:67
>   IP_EDMSforVentyx._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\IndusAXProject2013\IP_EDMSforVentyx\EDMSforVentyx_Default.cs:21
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object
>   o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +35    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2207

---

And the line of code is simply:

```
file.CopyTo(filepath + filename);
```

which is part of this:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= ((int) pages.Count); j++)
{
    PAGE page = (PAGE) pages[j];
    PageVersions versions = (PageVersions) page.Versions;
    int num4 = 0;
    num4 = (int) versions.Count;
    if (num4 < 1)
    {
        break;
    }

    PAGEVERSION pageversion = (PAGEVERSION) versions[num4];
    ObjectFile file = (ObjectFile) app.FileObject;
    filename = i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString() + ".tif";
    file.ObjectId = pageversion.ObjectId;
    file.PathId = (pageversion.PathId);
    file.GenerateNewFileName();
    file.CopyTo(filepath + filename);
    if (IsJpegHeader(filepath, filename))
    {
        this.DeleteImgFile(filepath, filename);
        file.CopyTo(filepath + (i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString() + ".jpg"));
    }
}
```

Anyway, thanks if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Maybe OS user who is running that process has no privileges to create file in your destination directory?

Comment: of course you don't include the part that dicatates whether you're escaping your file path properly or not hint hint.  On a related note, when you debug, what is the value of filepath + filename?

Comment: What type does `file` have? Looks like it is not `System.IO.File`.

Comment: @Kamil there's a more specific error for that: System.Security.SecurityException: Permission denied

Comment: @wRAR `XtenderSolutions.interop.AEXDBLib.IObjectFile.CopyTo(Object FileName) +0 `

Comment: @RandomUs1r Not necessarily. It'd be up to the COM wrapper to throw whatever exceptions it feels the need to.

Comment: I didn't think file was a COM object at first, but it looks like we may need a bit more detail on this one anyways.

Comment: is this the actual file path `IndusAXProject2013` or should it be `Indus\AX\Project2013` ...etc what happens when you step thru the code..? can you provide more debug information..?

Comment: Hi! It isn't a path or permission problem; the file actually gets copied as it is supposed to. It is coded as a.bin file but is actually a .tif, the copy process renames it so. It just seems that it doesn't KNOW it was successful, or doesn't sent an acknowledge of success back. I do notice there is a 500.0 error in the inetpub log, so maybe it is more a web issue.. Dunno. It doesn't use a COM object that I am aware of... The file path you are looking at is actually for the surce code. I haven't figured out how to get a debug on the test server in action.... Thanks for the interest everyone!

Comment: Hi again! Per the question above, below is the path statment. I am not sure it qualifies as correctly escaping the path, but it seems to be working.....

Comment: Oops. Should not hit the return key?                                                                string filepath = str4 + @"\temp\" + sessionID + @"\" + FieldValue + @"\";
DBConnection connection = new DBConnectionClass();